# How to do when load error Couldn't match expected type `IO (Maybe String)'

Tags: haskell

```
module REPL(REPL(..), repl) where
import qualified Control.Exception as E
import System.Console.Readline(readline, addHistory)

data REPL s = REPL {
    repl_init :: IO (String, s),        -- prompt and initial state
    repl_eval :: s -> String -> IO (Bool, s),       -- quit flag and new state
    repl_exit :: s -> IO ()
    }

repl :: REPL s -> IO ()
repl p = do
    (prompt, state) <- repl_init p
    let loop s = (do
        mline <- readline prompt
        case mline of
        Nothing -> loop s
        Just line -> do
            (quit, s') <- repl_eval p s line
            if quit then
            repl_exit p s'
             else do
            addHistory line
            loop s'
        ) E.catch undefined (\(e :: E.SomeException) -> putStrLn "Handled exception!"
        )
    loop state
```

Output:

```
REPL.hs:21:5:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO (Maybe String)'
           against inferred type `t -> Maybe String'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: mline <- readline prompt
    In the expression:
        (do { mline <- readline prompt;
              case mline of {
                Nothing -> loop s
                Just line
                  -> do { (quit, s') <- repl_eval p s line;
                          .... } } })
          E.catch
          undefined
          (\ (e :: E.SomeException) -> putStrLn "Handled exception!")
    In the definition of `loop':
        loop s = (do { mline <- readline prompt;
                       case mline of {
                         Nothing -> loop s
                         Just line -> do { ... } } })
                   E.catch
                   undefined
                   (\ (e :: E.SomeException) -> putStrLn "Handled exception!")
```

Comment: I think E.catch should be within backticks, and the `undefined` after it has to go as well. After that, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your previous question you have removed the backticks, `, around your `E.catch` statement.  My answer to that question didn't use backticks because I wasn't calling `catch` infix.  You can either use catch post-fix without backticks:

```
let loop s = E.catch (do ...) (\(e :: E.SomeException) -> ...)
```

or you can use catch infix with the backticks:

```
let loop s = (do ...) `E.catch` (\(e :: E.SomeException) -> ...)
```

Also, the `undefined` was me just forcing an exception for sake of an example on the GHCi REPL - it took the place of the `(do ..)` statement in your code.

Comment: I will try it tonight, feedback you later.